# Get all the csv strings of a list as single elements in a new list with a comprehension list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list as follows:

```
listt = ['34','56,67','45,56,67','45']
```

I would like to get a list of single values.

this is my code:

```
new_list=[]
for element in listt:
    if ',' in element:
        subl=element.split(',')
        new_list = new_list + subl
    else:
        new_list.append(element)
```

result:

```
['34', '56', '67', '45', '56', '67', '45']
```

Is there actually a way to do this with a comprehension list? (i.e. one liner).
It looks like too much code for such a tiny thing.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spam = ['34','56,67','45,56,67','45']
eggs = [num for item in spam for num in item.split(',')]
print(eggs)
```

output

```
['34', '56', '67', '45', '56', '67', '45']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listt = ['34','56,67','45,56,67','45']

print(','.join(listt).split(','))
```

Prints:

```
['34', '56', '67', '45', '56', '67', '45']
```